# HTML5 drag and drop with react

Tags: reactjs

I have a Container which has binding for drag and drop functions

```
        constructor(props,context) {
            super(props,context);
            this.allowDrop = this.allowDrop.bind(this);
            this.drag = this.drag.bind(this);
            this.drop = this.drop.bind(this);
            this.dragOver = this.dragOver.bind(this);
}



      allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('text', ev.target.id);
    ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  }

  drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    console.log(ev);
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }

  dragOver(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
```

And a presentational component

```
<div className="row">
    <div className="col-xs-6">
      <p className="lead">Possibilities</p>
      <ul onDrop={props.drop} onDragOver={props.allowDrop} style={{listStyle:'none',border:'1px solid #ccc',padding:'5px',overflow:'scroll',borderRadius:'3px',minHeight:'100px'}}>
        <li id='drag1' draggable='true' onDragStart={props.drag} style={{userSelect:'none'}}>item 1</li>
        <li id='drag2' draggable='true' onDragStart={props.drag}>item 2</li>
        <li id='drag3' draggable='true' onDragStart={props.drag}>item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div className="col-xs-6">
      <p className="lead">Selected</p>
      <ul onDrop={props.drop} onDragOver={props.allowDrop} style={{listStyle:'none',border:'1px solid #ccc',padding:'5px',overflow:'scroll',borderRadius:'3px',minHeight:'100px'}}>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The issue i am facing is when i try to reorder, one li is nesting as child to other.

The problem is drop function where i need to refer the ul.. How to do this?

Comment: This one may be interesting for you: https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd

Comment: @jmac the library you have mentioned is more complex. html5 dnd sounds simple. i understand dnd api of html5 is a mess but for basic dnd it should be achievable using this.

Comment: Curious to see if you were able to solve your solution. Also would React's "ref" help you?

Answer (score 0):

In your drop handler, ev.currentTarget should refer to your ul item.